# How to check that a number probably/likely has a divisor having a specific bit length/in range?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, factorization-theory

Given a randomly generated $\alpha\in\Bbb N$ where $\alpha$ is large thus hard to factor (no small prime composites). How to check that a divisor $F\in\Bbb N$ with a specific bitlengh $n\in\Bbb N∧n<\alpha$ so within the range 2<sup>$n$</sup> to 2<sup>n+1</sup>−1 likely exists ? (though in my case the bitlength to check for probably existing divisors is $bitlength(\alpha)÷2$ which means is bounded by the square root)

I’m interested in prime but finding a composite $F$ is Ok too.

for example, if $\alpha$ is 386 bits long, could ecm be abused and bounds be defined to have to test ~17,000 curves for ruling out the possibility at 98% of a 193‑bits divisor ? If yes, would this be faster than using Gnfs for factoring the number completely ?

Comment: This is likely almost as hard as factoring for an arbitrary number. If you know more about the number in question, it might be possible to do something more clever.

Comment: @JoshuaZ I just know the hash output used as randonmness from a chosen seed. So I know the bitlength and that s all. This isn t about finding it but if 1 has a very high chance to exists.